# Use values from one table as keys in another (PHP)

Tags: php

I have an array whose values I want to use as keys in an hash.
I have a:

```
$x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$r = 'result;
```

OR

```
$obj=['name'=>'a/b/c', 'value'=>'result']
```

I want to convert it to:

```
$x['a']['b']['c'] = 'result';
```

How to embrace it?

Comment: Did you want that result in a multi-dimensional array or separately for each value ('a','b' and 'c') ?

Comment: $x[$x[0]][$x[1]][$x[2]] = $r;

Comment: The result is to be a multidimensional array.

Version $x [$x[0]][$x[1]][$x[2]] = $r; it will not work if we do not know the number of values in the $x array at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a recursive function

```
function convert(array $keys, $value) {
  if(count($keys) === 0){
    return $value;       
  }
  $key = $keys[0];
  $rest = array_slice($keys, 1);
  return [$key => convert($rest, $value)];
}
```

In the first case

`$x = convert($x, $result);`

second case

`$x = convert(explode('/', $obj['name']), $obj['value']);`

Comment: This code is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to create an object array a,b and c and want to fill it with a resut right?

**Your array:**
$x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

Let me first explain $x.

if you var_dump this array you will get:

**PHP-code**

```
$x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var_dump($x);
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" }
```

But actually you wanted to create something like this?

**PHP-code**

```
$r = 'result';
$x['a'] = $x['b'] = $x['c'] = $r;
var_dump($x);
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) { ["c"]=> string(6) "result" ["b"]=> string(6) "result" ["a"]=> string(6) "result" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$r = 'result';

$temp = [];

for ($i = count($x)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  if ($i === count($x)-1) {
    $temp[$x[$i]] = $r;
  } else {
    $temp[$x[$i]] = $temp;
    unset($temp[$x[$i+1]]);
  }
}

print_r($temp);
```

Comment: Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30209727)